Why would the Boeing 777 not be included in Jane's All the World's Aircraft – In Service?
I am currently sitting in front of the last nine issues of Jane's All the World's Aircraft – In Service at the British Library (issues 2013–2014 to 2023–2024).
To my great surprise, the Boeing 777 is not included in any of these issues.
Am I missing something obvious?
Just to make sure, I even checked under "T" (for "Triple-Seven")…, but still nothing. At a price tag of USD ~2,000/volume, I would have expected Jane's not to omit an aircraft like the 777 from their volumes.
Edit: The 787 Dreamliner is also missing from the latest issues…. Could it be that Boeing is not keen on Jane publishing a nicely formatted list of aircraft weights and performance parameters?
For example, here is the index of the 2013–2014 issue:


Interestingly, the 777 can be found in the online version.

The Next Gen series of 737s is also not shown on that list (737-600 thru 737-900). Is there another list of Boeing aircraft under something besides that “Boeing Commercial Airplanes” header?

nor is the 747-8. Neither are the 767-300 and -400 passenger versions

You're looking in the wrong volume. The In Service volume contains aircraft types that are in service but out of production. You need to look in the Development and Production volume, as the 777 is both in production and has variants under development.

Wow - that is some really bad choice of Title !
